# My Character Run Animation is not Playing in Game Engine

Tags: animation, game-engine

I've followed numerous tutorials and read a lot of material on what I could have done wrong, but nothing is working. I would keep troubleshooting myself, but I've already spent A LOT of time trying to figure this out, and I see no end in sight.

I have my character's run animation on frames 1 - 11 (1-10 for the animation cycle), and a jump animation later, I think 20 - 44. All I want to do is get the run cycle working and moving with the parented cube via the <kbd>W</kbd> key. Once I have that figured out I want to start adding other animations.

I just have no idea what I need to be doing at this point, or if I messed up a while ago. Any help is very very much appreciated.

File Attached, any assistance is highly appreciated!

Blend File: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=43899

[image: Screencap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Activate an action actuator that plays the run action starting at frame 1 ending at frame 11. Let it play in Loop stop mode to get an endless cycle.

## Details

You need to parent the skin mesh objects (with Armature Deform option) to the armature.